# Unable to inject scripts in Microsoft office 365 products

Tags: visual-c++, vbscript, office365, jscript, inject

we have software being used for single sign on for various applications and it captures fields on their XPATH basis and inject credentials for various username and password by using mshtml library and it create instance for security prompt displayed when we open a word, ppt or excel. it is found that once we have migrated to latest office 365 user is not able run any scripts like jscripts and vbscripts which are used for getting username and password data from security prompt for excel, ppt and word for office 365.

We are getting access denied issue as HRESULT error shows an error code of -2147024891.

Can you please let me know as to what changes in settings need to be made so that user is able to inject vbscripts and jscripts for office 365 products.
.

Comment: This almost sounds like a Microsoft Office 365 Trust Center issue.  Ensure your add-ins, code-signing certificates, trusted locations, and/or macro settings are properly set and permitted in Microsoft Office 365 to allow your software, libraries, and scripts to function correctly.

Comment: Thanks i checked for the trust center options but where i can find options to allow scripts to run.
Do i need to set the trust center options for all office 365 products manually

Comment: Can you provide more details?  For example, the software being used for single sign-on, the scripts and source code being used to accomplish the task you are describing, a code snippet of the script injection technique being used, the process reporting the error, the account context(s) in which the process(es) and script(s) are running, and if any group policies, software restriction policies, or other security software may be preventing your scripts from executing, etc.

Comment: CComObject<CMyScriptHost>* pHost = 
   NS_COM_UTILS::CreateNewComObject<CComObject<CMyScriptHost> >();
  pHost->SetEC(pEC);
  pHost->SetGenerator(pGen);
  this->m_oScriptSite = (IActiveScriptSite*)pHost;
  HRESULT hr = this->m_oScriptEngine.CreateInstance(wstrLang.c_str());
  if(FAILED(hr))
  {
     throw (int) E_LoadingScriptEngine;
  }

Comment: Above code is utilized where it fails during createinstance.
CMyScriptHost is an interface for various com pointer like IActiveScriptSite, IActiveScript etc
IActiveScriptPtr m_oScriptEngine; used from activscp.h from Microsoft file
CMyScriptHost is an interface for various com pointer like IActiveScriptSite, IActiveScript etc

Comment: Basically we use hooking technique and whenever window security prompt appears for office 365 product when we open any file like excel and word then above code executes which createinstance for the particular language and code is supplied which gets parsed after instance gets created.
Createinstance always fails with access denied like 2147024891 error code

Comment: Were the July and August cumulative updates for Windows applied to your systems?  If so, there might be a side-effect of Microsoft disabling VBScript for untrusted security zones.  Also, could there be a disconnect between 32-bit COM and 64-bit O365?  Finally, are you certain your hook is actually loaded in the process space of the O365 security prompt?  Just wondering if MS O365 might actively be preventing such hooking (and COM activation) of its prompts for security reasons.  BTW, tagging your question with C++ might help lure some more productive responses.